# Xcode 10 troubles: How can I put the app's build inside the archives panel and then load it on the App Store Connect site?

Tags: swift4, xcode10

I completed to code my first app with Swift 4.

I have an Apple Developer account and I'd like to share my app on the App Store.
I've done all the correct procedure but, when I try to load the app's build on the App Store Connect site, I'm not able to do it!
Checking inside Xcode I've seen that my app's build isn't present in the archives panel (reading around, it looks to be the issue)... I tried to follow the indications given by the program's help instrument but I got crazy doing it!

How can I put the app's build inside the archives panel and then load it on the App Store Connect site?

Comment: "have an Apple Developer account" A _paid_ developer account? You can't do this with a free account.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Product > Archive in Xcode will create an archive of your project. After creating the archive, choose Window > Organizer to open the Organizer window. Click the Archives tab in the Organizer to access your archives and upload them to App Store Connect. Select an archive and click the Distribute App button to upload the archive to App Store Connect.

Comment: Should mention that in order to do that, must choose "generic ios device" as destination.